# ng-repeat: Color table background dynamically

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to set the background in a table's cell according to the value resulting from `ng-repeat`. So far I have following code:

```html
<table id="myTableDisk" width="100%" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Mount</th>
      <th scope="col">Size</th>
      <th scope="col">Used</th>
      <th scope="col">Free</th>
      <th scope="col">Use %</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="mount in msg.payload"
        ng-style="{backgroundColor: $scope.getBackgroundColor(mount.usedPercent)}"
        $scope.getBackgroundColor(value) {
            if(value <= 75)
              return 'red';
            if(value > 90)
              return 'blue';
            return 'black'
    }>
      <th align="left" scope="row">{{mount.mount}}</th>
      <td align="right">{{mount.size}}</td>
      <td align="right">{{mount.used}}</td>
      <td align="right">{{mount.available}}</td>
      <td align="right">{{mount.usedPercent}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I have to issues with this code:

1. It does not work
2. If it would work, I assume it would color the entire table but I need to work on the `{{mount.usedPercent}}` td only

What is a practical way to achieve this in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ref 1**. You should define your `$scope.getBackgroundColor()` function in your controller, not in your template.

Also note `$scope` properties and methods are accessible in your template's expressions without having to prefix them with `$scope`. If you prefix them with `$scope`, you're actually trying to access `$scope.$scope.someProperty`, which does not exist (unless you define them, but defining a `$scope` property of `$scope` is to be avoided as it it would generate confusion and make your code harder to understand, debug and maintain).

**Ref 2**. If you need it on a particular `<td>`, just place it where you need it:

```
<tr ng-repeat="mount in msg.payload">
  <th align="left" scope="row">{{mount.mount}}</th>
  <td align="right">{{mount.size}}</td>
  <td align="right">{{mount.used}}</td>
  <td align="right">{{mount.available}}</td>
  <td align="right" 
      ng-style="{backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(mount.usedPercent)}"
  >{{mount.usedPercent}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you really want to define `someProperty` in the template, you definitely should not do it inside an `ng-repeat` (because it means you overwrite it on each iteration of `ng-repeat` and that's quite inefficient).
Remember, though, defining scope properties in template will make your code harder to maintain if your app grows in complexity and you do it in many places; soon you won't be able to figure out what is defined and where:

```
{{getBackgroundColor = value => value <= 75 ? 'red' : value > 90 ? 'blue' : 'black'}}
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="mount in msg.payload">
    ...
    <td ng-style="{backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(mount.usedPercent)}">
      {{mount.usedPercent}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works. Unfortunately not in Node-Red. Reading up on this I guess this is related to the fact that the NR Dashboards use some kind of wrapped Angular and one cannot declare an App or Controller.